# Почему Visual studio не видит библиотеки и классы shader Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d, шейдеры

Скрипты видит, а вот shader не видит подсказки.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Как вы поняли, что не видит?

Comment: методы белым цветом, например o.vertex, вот у o. подсказок нету

Comment: мне казалось что у всех не отображается это)